# Is it possible to get ALL dart code work sync?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am familiar with await-async conception, but I am writing a lot of linear code that should always run in single thread and synchronously. Also it's much easier to debug synchronously code.

Is it possible to make ALL code work synchronously? Regardless of async\await calls in code?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you await a function it will run that function before continuing to the next line. This makes it synchronous.

Comment: @EverydayEngineer That makes code have the same *structure* as synchronous code, but it doesn't make it synchronous.  Anyway, no, there is no supported way to make asynchronous code synchronous.

Comment: just don't use any async code? anyway this blog post by a dart engineer is good read about async function https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/